# Always getting Unauthorized after Spring boot migration

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

I an working on upgrading fron Spring boot 1 to Spring boot 2, but I have been stuck since 2 days.

The authentication used to work very fine on my React/Spring boot App, but after migrating every thing was fine but getting always 401 (Unauthorized) on my api/authenticate resource.

Here my security configuration after some changes:

```
@Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic()
                //.authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(PERMIT_ALL_GET_URLS).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, PERMIT_ALL_POST_URLS).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .logout().clearAuthentication(true)
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/logout")).invalidateHttpSession(true).and().csrf()
                .requireCsrfProtectionMatcher(new RequestMatcher() {
                    private Pattern allowedMethods = Pattern.compile("^(GET|HEAD|TRACE|OPTIONS)$");
                    @Override
                    public boolean matches(HttpServletRequest request) {
                        // No CSRF due to public requests
                        if (stringContainsItemFromList(request.getRequestURI(), PERMIT_ALL_POST_URLS_PATTERN_PREFIX))
                            return false;
                        if (Arrays.asList(PERMIT_ALL_POST_URLS).contains(request.getRequestURI()))
                            return false;
                        // No CSRF due to allowed methods
                        if (allowedMethods.matcher(request.getMethod()).matches())
                            return false;
                        // CSRF for everything else
                        return true;
                    }
                }).csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
                .ignoringAntMatchers("/api/external/uploadBulkVerifications/*");
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint);
        http.headers().xssProtection().xssProtectionEnabled(true);
        http.headers().xssProtection().block(false);
        http.headers().defaultsDisabled().contentTypeOptions();
        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(2).expiredUrl("/");
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
```

Am I missing something or I need also to review the `authenticate()` method

**EDIT**:

With wrong credentials I have got:

`2019-07-02 11:02:13.100 DEBUG 79640 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Authentication request for failed: org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: gaca.api.errors.authentication.0001
2019-07-02 11:02:13.100 DEBUG 79640 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Trying to match using RequestHeaderRequestMatcher [expectedHeaderName=X-Requested-With, expectedHeaderValue=XMLHttpRequest]
2019-07-02 11:02:13.100 DEBUG 79640 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.a.DelegatingAuthenticationEntryPoint : Match found! Executing org.springframework.security.web.authentication.HttpStatusEntryPoint@17b900b4
2019-07-02 11:02:13.101 DEBUG 79640 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
2019-07-02 11:02:13.101 DEBUG 79640 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed`

I would like to know which filter is blocking me

And with correct credentials, I am getting:

`2019-07-02 11:07:06.397 DEBUG 79640 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] e.g.c.S.LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider : User account credentials have expired`

I am not handling any kind of expired credentials

Comment: There was a shift on mentality while bumping the Spring Boot version, meaning that for Spring Boot 1 ( Spring Security 4 ) everything was unsecured by default and you had to explicitly define the secure endpoints. In Spring Boot 2 ( Spring Security 5 ) everything is secured by default and you have to explicitly define which endpoints should be unsecured.  The easiest way to debug through this is by putting breakpoints in Spring Security filters and determine which filter is rejecting your request.

Comment: Thanks @BogdanSucaciu I have made some update

Comment: Where that `LimitLoginAuthenticationProvider` comes from? It doesn't seem to be part of the standard Spring Security package.